# Simulate a key press without targeting an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to simulate a key press. However I have just been able to find this:

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 75;
$("whatever").trigger(press);
```

Where "whatever" is an input field or something. However I don't need to target any element. How can I simulate a key press (the 'k' key to be specific) without targeting any element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically

Comment: Where is the key being pressed if not somewhere in the interface?

Comment: i guess your target element can be body, document or window (i would go for body, it is here i used to place the keypressed events)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to target any element, you will have to target the `body` directly, that way, any key should trigger what you want

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").keypress(function(){
        alert('hey');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Targeting the body will give you the sense of targeting nothing.

[CharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode#Notes)

```js
function showChar(e)
{
alert("Key Pressed: " + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) + "\n"
      + "charCode: " + e.charCode);
}
```

```html
<body onkeypress="showChar(event);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$('body').keypress(function(e){
  if ( e.which == 75 ) { 
    alert('hey k was pressed');
  }
});
```

Have a look at [this](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) list of char codes